# Extract all categories id for a product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a php script that extracts info about products from my store and it puts it into a csv.
At the moment i am only extracting the default category id with

```
$item['id_categorie'] = $product->id_category_default;
```

Is it possible to extract the ids of all the categories assigned to a product using something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, once you have the product object you can use the `getProductCategoriesFull` method to get all categories for a product as an associative array with the category ID and name as the key/value pairs.

Example:

```
$product->getProductCategoriesFull()
```